# postgresql client overflow

Tags: macos, postgresql, client-server, homebrew

I keep getting the error:

> FATAL:  sorry, too many clients
>   already

I never had the problem before, but I recently upgraded to version 9.03 and also OS X lion preview release 2.  It doesn't seem to matter how idle the processes are, they never die.  I have to restart postgres every half hour or so.  I'm using postgres via Rails 3 and Navicat, never had a problem with either before now and stopping both clients does nothing to solve the problem.

Any ideas or settings I'm missing?  Not sure what settings I should display here for my setup, but everything should be default. Installed postgres using HOMEBREW.

Comment: currently set to 20 max connections

Comment: What activity is causing a connection to open?  Are you issuing connections in your app logic?  Are users using your system or is it just a development instance?

Comment: development, that's why it's annoying.  It's just me, and every 30 minutes or so, I have to start killing idle processes or restart it.

Comment: also, "pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast" doesn't seem to work very often.  Usually I get "pg_ctl: server does not shut down"

Comment: In my experience, the "pg_ctl: server does not shut down" message is caused by launchctl starting the postgresql process directly after shutdown. I don't know a lot about launchctl, but it looks like it has some kind of nanny process that is monitoring the postgresql process and starting it up again after it is shutdown. I ran "launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist" to get this to work (but now I also have to start postgresql manually on reboot).

Comment: Are you using `establish_connection` for any remote database connections? I was having this issue for a while... Let me know if that's the case and I can share the workaround that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely go into postgresql.conf and edit max_connections and post the existing value.To see how many connections you have an what they are doing select from pg_stat_activity.  Maybe your bleeding connections?

See this link
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/runtime-config-connection.html